# liquibase diff changelog against hibernate/realdb

Tags: liquibase

So we have a set o database changelogs and we want to achieve that whenever developer make a change in *`hbm` file, he run a `diff` comparing changelog commited to our codebase against edited hbm schema - so we can get new changelog with his recent modifications.

`Liquibase-hibernate` allows to compare hbm schema agaisnt any database, but is there a way to compare hbm schema against changelog xml file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not currently possible. Comparing a database (or hibernate mapping) to a changelog is a is a popular request, but it hasn't been implemented yet. The biggest problem is that to solve it for the general case we need an SQL parser in order to handle   and  blocks.

It can be done for a subset of all change logs where just standard  etc. tags are used, but it has not been implemented yet, unfortunately.